# How to prevent ░ or ▀ changing to &#9617,etc?

Tags: html, blogger, html-encode

i am trying to add this in source code of my page inside a comment.

However,when i save,the characters change from this http://img.ctrlv.in/5134b28e330fa.jpg

to

http://img.ctrlv.in/5134b28e7a5b0.jpg

i tried [encoding](http://htmlentities.net/) the characters,but in vain.They still change.

Is there any trick to prevent them from changing?thanks a lot

Comment: This question is very localized and off topic. It is unlikely to help future visitors. Voting to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You are at the mercy of Blogger's template processor.

Comment: ░░░░░░░░░░░░░▄▄▄▄▄▄▄░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░▄▀▀▀░░░░░░░▀▄░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░▄▀░░░░░░░░░░░░▀▄░░░░░░
░░░░░░▄▀░░░░░░░░░░▄▀▀▄▀▄░░░░░
░░░░▄▀░░░░░░░░░░▄▀░░██▄▀▄░░░░
░░░▄▀░░▄▀▀▀▄░░░░█░░░▀▀░█▀▄░░░ ░░░█░░█▄░░░░█░░░▀▄░░░░░▐░█░░░
░░▐▌░░█▀░░░▄▀░░░░░▀▄▄▄▄▀░░█░░
░░▐▌░░█░░░▄▀░░░░░░░░░░░░░░█░░
░░▐▌░░░▀▀▀░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▐▌░
░░▐▌░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▄░░░░░░▐▌░
░░▐▌░░░░░░░░░▄░░░░░█░░░░░░▐▌░ ░░░█░░░░░░░░░▀█▄░░▄█░░░░░░▐▌░
░░░▐▌░░░░░░░░░░▀▀▀▀░░░░░░░▐▌░
░░░░█░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░█░░
░░░░▐▌▀▄░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▐▌░░
░░░░░█░░▀░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▀░░░ok